# How to upload Image using Avs Import in product?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to upload image by programmatically.

I have to imagefolder and 
i put it media/import/imagefolder.
and My code is

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
 ini_set('memory_limit', '50024M');
$attrId = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getResource()->getAttribute('media_gallery')
->getAttributeId();
$path = Mage::getBaseDir('media').'\import'.DS;
echo $path;
$data = array();
echo "<br>";
echo "<pre>";
$files = glob($path.'*.jpg' ,  GLOB_BRACE);
//$path_parts = explode(".",$files);
    foreach($files as $key=>$value)   
    {  
        $filename = basename($value);
        //echo $filename;
        $path_parts = explode(".",$filename);

        unset($path_parts[1]);

        $data[] = array(
        'sku' => $path_parts[0],
        '_type' => 'simple',
        'status' => 1,
        'visibility' => 4,
        '_media_image'=> $value,
        '_media_attribute_id'=>$attrId,
        '_media_is_disabled' =>0,
        'image'=> $filename,
        'small_image'=> $filename,
        'thumbnail'=> $filename,

);
//$data = array_values($data);

    } print_r($data);
    try {
    /** @var $import AvS_FastSimpleImport_Model_Import */
    $import = Mage::getModel('fastsimpleimport/import');
    $import->processProductImport($data);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r($import->getErrorMessages());
}

echo "Check Now";

?>
```

but Image not uploaded.

so how can i do?

Comment: Is this on windows or linux? Also, is it finding any images at all? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: this is on windows and no one get error

Comment: Try to debug a little, does it find any images, is the image path valid etc. We have very little to go on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need  to use `DS`  as directory spectator.  not `\`

If you have using this then it   must **create issue in window & etc os.**

```
$path = Mage::getBaseDir('media').'\import'.DS;
```

**should be**

```
$path = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'import'.DS;
```

**Mage::getBaseDir('media') =YourMagentoInstacePath/mediaFolder**

Answer (score 0):

There is a minor  mistake and I changed this

```
$path = Mage::getBaseDir('media').'\import'.DS;
```

to

```
$path = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'\import'.DS;
```

Comment: Mage::getBaseUrl('media') give the media url not media path...your answer is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `Mage_Core_Model_Config_Options`.